# Pandas count on str with total

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on analyzing survey data with Pandas and have the below raw data

```
Dept |  Q3  | Q4  |
-----| ---- |---- |
HR   | Yes  | Yes |
IT   | No   | Yes |
HR   | No   | Yes |
HR   | Yes  | Yes |
IT   | No   | Yes |
IT   | Yes  | Yes |
```

I'm trying to groupby Dept & Q3 and get the count of all yes responses with the total responses and percentage of yes in that question. Something like this

```
Dept |  Q3 - Yes | Total |  %
-----| ----------| ----- | --
HR   |     2     |  3    |
IT   |     1     |  3    |
```

I've used the below code to group and get the total yes count but not sure how to add total and % to same dataframe for that groupby

```
df.groupby("Dept")['Q3'].apply(lambda x: x[x.str.contains('Yes')].count())
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm kind of stuck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
out = df.groupby("Dept")["Q3"].agg([lambda x: (x == "Yes").sum(), "count"])
out.columns = ["Q3 - Yes", "Total"]

out["%"] = out["Q3 - Yes"] / out["Total"]
```

Output

```
print(out)
      Q3 - Yes  Total         %
Dept                           
HR           2      3  0.666667
IT           1      3  0.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the total counts seperately and merge the dataframes.

```
df2=df.groupby("Dept")['Q3'].apply(lambda x: x[x.str.contains('Yes')].count()
df3=df.groupby("Dept")['Q3'].count()
df4=pd.merge(df2,df3,on="Dept",how='outer')
print(df4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `groupby` + `agg`

```
out = df.groupby('Dept').agg(lambda x : x.eq('Yes').sum()).join(df.groupby('Dept').size().to_frame('Total'))
Out[42]: 
      Q3  Q4  Total
Dept               
HR     2   3      3
IT     0   2      2
It     1   1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the results for the third quarter, as your answer shows:

```
(pd.crosstab(df.Dept, df.Q3)
 .assign(Total=lambda df: df.sum(1))
 .loc[:, ["Yes", "Total"]])

Q3  Yes     Total
Dept        
HR  2       3
IT  1       3
```